# Finding duplicate rows and related records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I have a database that was migrated into a new schema. The old database had no referential integrity and so I need to get rid of lots of duplicates.

I have a table of `RegisteredVehicles`:

```
id | plate | state 
#  | 1425  | il
#  | 3322  | il
```

And a table of `ParkingRequests`:

```
id | date   | registeredVehicleId (FK)
#  | 2/2/12 | #
```

The relatoinship is one to many - one registered vehicle to many requests.

The following query gets me each duplicate record by `Plate` and `State` and also outputs each `RegisteredVehicle's` Id.

```
select Id, Plate, [State] from RegisteredVehicles where Plate in (
select plate from RegisteredVehicles group by Plate having count(*) > 1
)
```

Which gives me something like this

```
Id                                      Plate   State
036d59f1-d928-40f2-b373-049122202bff    0000000 IL
615e2fab-8b43-4e42-b6f0-268038bba949    0000000
```

I am trying to get a count of parking request per each vehicle row returned in the above code block. Something like this

```
Id | Plate | State | # Requests
1  | 222   | IL    | 2
2  | 333   | IL    | 4
```

But am having issues making the query more complex than it already is. This itself took me quite a while to get working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this query :

```
SELECT
    A.ID,
    A.PLATE,
    A.STATE AS [STATE],
    COUNT(A.ID) AS [NO OF REQUESTS]
FROM REGISTEREDVEHICLES A
LEFT JOIN PARKINGREQUESTS B
    ON B.REGISTEREDVEHICLEID = A.ID
WHERE
    A.PLATE IN(
                    SELECT 
                        PLATE 
                    FROM REGISTEREDVEHICLES 
                    GROUP BY PLATE
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
    GROUP BY     
    A.ID,
    A.PLATE,
    A.STATE
```